# Rails4 - How to add from name to emails sent from my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sendgrid

I have a rails app on heroku and I use sendgrid addon to send emails.

When I receive emails from Stack Exchange in my gmail, I receive it as follows.

```
Stack Exchange <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
```

But when I receive email from my website, it's like the following

```
noreply@mywebsite.com via sendgrid.info
```

How can I do the same with the emails from my website?

Is it possible to send it like this from my rails app?

```
My Website <noreply@mywebsite.com>
```

Does it have anything to do with my rails app at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `"My Website <noreply@mywebsite.com>"` as the `from` value. (Yes, this is standard, and yes, ActionMailer will handle it as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "noreply@mywebsite.com" with "My Website <noreply@mywebsite.com>" where ever you are specifying from address.